# Can Dragon Naturally Speaking premium be used for programming?

Tags: voice-recognition, naturallyspeaking

I have found three people on the net that say they use Dragon Naturally Speaking Pro for programming. I am unable to find anything stating whether or not this can be done efficiently with the premium version.

I cannot really afford the pro version. And I do not want to waste my money on premium if it will not get the job done.

If it makes a difference, I mainly do PHP / MySQL.

Comment: This might be more appropriate at programmers.

Comment: You should word this to be less subjective, ask for quantifiable pros and/or cons.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting [Nuance](http://nuance.com) and asking them. They might be able to enumerate the differences between the versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, premium works fine.  Quoting the FAQ on programming by voice (Q4.1) at http://vocola.net/programming-by-voice-FAQ.html:

Dragon NaturallySpeaking comes in several versions; you want either professional or premium. The primary claimed value of professional over premium is that professional allows creating voice commands using a 2006 version of Visual Basic. Given that there are free open source tools for creating voice commands that are vastly better and that professional costs substantially more than premium, you will probably want to stick with premium.